# Using sendto() and recvfrom() to deliver datagram

Tags: udp

If the sender uses sendto() for a few times, and receiver uses recvfrom() in a while loop, when the 2nd datagram arrives before the receiver finish processing the 1st one, will it get lost?

Comment: Pending datagrams will wait in the socket buffer.  If you are too slow, they will pile up and eventually can be lost.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your architecture,driver.

The packets that arrive at receiver are normally placed in driver's receive queue and processed accordingly like passing to IP layer's queue(based on architecture). If there is any overflow here, then it will be dropped at driver itself or IP layer. However, if has passed those layers but if the receive socket buffer(the amount of space for UDP queued in UDP socket) is full, then the UDP packets will be dropped else it will not be dropped.

netstat is one of the handy tool in such scenarios. *netstat -s* shall list statistics protocol-wise. The *-p* option can be used to display for specific protocol.

If you want a proper synchronization between sender and receiver, it shall be feasible only if receiver intimates sender by some means (or some kind of flow control mechanism). UDP protocol does not support it. If you are looking for such synchronization, then you need to select TCP protocol.